# jQuery Datepicker not selecting date? Conflict?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to setup my datepicker but its displaying inline? I can select a date but it doesn't insert the date in to the textbox?

I've included the jquery ui css within my stylesheet, added the three .js files, core.ui, widget.ui, and datepicker, not getting any errors? Any ideas?

http://www.florever.com.au/cart

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
            $( "#delivery-date" ).datepicker();
        });


</script>

<input type="text" size="30" name="delivery-date" id="delivery-date" class="hasDatepicker" val="">
```

Comment: How many times do you include jQuery in your page? Seems like two times. I see 1.3.2 loaded followed by an attempt to load 1.4.x from Google CDN.

Answer (score 8):

I've solved it turned out I had multiple instances of an ID...

I'm voting to delete this as I'm not sure its really going to help anyone.

Comment: Well it helped me !

Answer (score 0):

Where is jQuery? I do not see it anywhere in your source. You must include jQuery before any libraries/widgets which depend on jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI here -->
<!-- jQuery tools here -->
<!-- etc -->
```

Comment: I think its included within tools.js? I've added https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js just incase but still nothing?